# c# regex to search text but not report it in the matched groups

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following output from a utility I use for data processing.

```
Processed output from W765 build 66721
File target: C:\Documents and Settings\Jon\Desktop\test\1024\cards.dat
Cards loaded: 876 1456 1457 1459 2072
Errors encountered (0)
Warnings encountered (0)
Pass
```

I want a .Net regex to be able to retrieve as groups just `876 1456 1457 1459 2072` and nothing else.

I have got to this that works

```
([0-9]\d+)+
```

but unfortunately it yields

Found 8 matches:

```
765
66721
1024
876
1456
1457
1459
2072
```

I thought this would work instead

```
.*(?:Cards loaded\: )([0-9]\d+)+
```

but it doesn't.

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Thank you
Jonathan Bolton

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
Cards loaded:(?'digits'(\d|\s)+)
```

this will return in the named group "digits" the numeric portion you need

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try `Cards loaded\: [\d\s]+` to return `Cards loaded: 876 1456 1457 1459 2072`, then on that string, do `\d+` to get each of the relevant results.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
(?m)(?<=^Cards loaded: (?:\d+\s)*)\d+
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to just be a regex, i.e. just remove the guff you don't want from the begining before parsing

```
string toSearch = @"Processed output from W765 build 66721 File target: C:\Documents and Settings\Jon\Desktop\test\1024\cards.dat Cards loaded: 876 1456 1457 1459 2072 Errors encountered (0) Warnings encountered (0) Pass";
string shortened = toSearch.Substring(toSearch.IndexOf("Cards loaded:"));
var matches = Regex.Matches(shortened,@"([0-9]\d+)+");
```